# React respond with multiple console.log

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, components, console.log

I made a functional component, and my axios request respond with 2 undefined and 1 response 200. I don't understand why ?

Here is my component :

```
import { UidContext } from "../components/AppContext"
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default function Balance() {
    const uid = useContext(UidContext)
    const [userWallet, setUserWallet] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (uid !== null) {
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/balance/${uid}`)
                .then((res) => (setUserWallet(res.data[0])))
        }
    }, [uid]);

    console.log(userWallet);

    return (
        <section>
            Test
        </section>
    )
}
```

#### Here is the response : Result

[image]

(ps : I use React Context in my App.js to store the users's ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log` will run every time your component renders, and your component re-renders every time or a prop change, or the state change or in this case the context changes. So I believe this is what is going on:

1. First render of your component ("on mount"), the userWallet is undefined.
2. Second render of your component ("context change"), the uid is setted by the Contexts and thus triggering a re render.
3. Third render ("because of `setUserWallet`"), the userWallet isn't undefined.

I want to note that I believe that your request is just running 1 time. If you move the console.log into the `then` cb of the axio promise, then you will see that it runs just 1 time, unless the uid object changes frequently, then every time the uid changes the request will be called again

Comment: Ok thank you very much, you are right. In the .then, it display just one log.
The way I did it is the good way ? Or is there something better optimized ?

Comment: No problem! Yeah! @JohanBRAZILLIER I guess one thing you could do so that your component gets a bit more cleaner, is moving all that fetching logic to a custom hook, such as useUserWallet, where you have the useContext, useState and useEffect in the same place, and in the Balance component you will just have: `const userWallet = useUserWallet()`. This way the logic og getting the userwallet is not the Balance component responsability

Comment: Great idea. Thank you very much